# how can count a fix date inbox sms in android

Tags: android, sms, counter

I am trying to develop a SMS counter app in which I want to count all SMS of the present date. i don't want to count total inbox SMS. I am using following code but not getting the exact result. It's counting total inbox SMS.

TextView view = new TextView(this);

```
    Uri uriSMSURI = Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox");
    Cursor cur = getContentResolver().query(uriSMSURI, null, null, null,null);
    /*
    int nsm = 0;
    while(cur.moveToNext()){
    nsm+= + cur.getCount();
    }
    */
    String sms = "";

   while ( cur.moveToNext());{
     //   sms += "From :" + cur.getString(2) + " : " + cur.getString(11)+"\n";   
   //    sms += cur.getString(2); 
        sms += "Total SMS in the INBOX : "+cur.getCount();
   }
    view.setText(sms);

    setContentView(view);
```

I am a new learner. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
Uri uriSMSURI = Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox");
    long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long last24 = now - 24*60*60*1000;//24h in millis
    String[] selectionArgs = new String[]{Long.toString(last24)};
    String selection = "date" + ">?";
    String[] projection = new String[]{"date"};
    Cursor cur = getContentResolver().query(uriSMSURI, projection, selection, selectionArgs,null);

    String sms = String.valueOf(cur.getCount());
```

This is the Exact resul what i wanted thanks for giving me quick reply

Comment: You didn't need to copy paste what I told you just to accept your own answer you know.

Comment: i want to close this question how to close this

Answer (score 6):

If you are trying to count the number of sms received within the last 24h you may do something like this (not sure if this actually work because I didn't tested it, but you get the idea) :

```
Uri uriSMSURI = Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox");
long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
long last24 = now - 24*60*60*1000;//24h in millis
String[] selectionArgs = new String[]{Long.toString(last24);
String selection = "WHERE " + "date" + ">?";
Cursor cur = getContentResolver().query(uriSMSURI, null, selection, selectionArgs,null);
```

Then a simple `cur.getCount()` should get you the number of sms received.

Comment: Thanks for your Quick reply. i tried above code but its not working emulator forcing to close

Comment: What is your log when force closing ?
I may have forgot 2 things (as i said I did not test)
Try something like this :


`Uri uriSMSURI = Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox");
long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
long last24 = now - 24*60*60*1000;//24h in millis
String[] selectionArgs = new String[]{Long.toString(last24)};
String selection = "date" + ">?";

String[] projection = new String[]{"date"}
Cursor cur = getContentResolver().query(uriSMSURI, projection, selection, selectionArgs,null);`

Comment: thanks for your kind reply now its not forcing to close
but in your code what will store the counting of the sms and provide result?   in my code i am using     String sms = "";          to get the UI output

Comment: As I already said, a simple cur.getCount() after the code I provided should be enough. If you really want to put it in a string, just do something like String sms = String.valueOf(cur.getCount());

Comment: thank you sir from my bottom of heart i got the result but i have a doubt related to the code, will it count the all 24 hours inbox sms or it will count for the current date like all inbox sms of 6/2/2013.
please suggest me..... Thanks in advance

Comment: WHERE is not required